# Categorical observed, Binomial latent

Tags: bayesian, categorical-data, binomial-distribution, latent-variable

This might be a trivial problem but wondering if there's a known model formulation for this problem:

- Ordered Categorical observed variable with k levels
- Trying to estimate the parameter (theta) of a latent Bernoulli/Binomial variable
- The latent and observed related by a k-length vector of probabilities

  - e.g. if observed=5 for a particular data point, data point has a 0.92 probability of success on the latent, observed=4 data point=0.81 success etc.

Does what I'm asking make sense? Or have I thought myself into a corner?

Comment: Are you, in effect, trying to integrate out the categorical variable to get an estimate of the unconditional probability of the latent Bernoulli variable?

Comment: I hadn't thought of it that way - but in effect that might be what I'm trying to do.
I should've also made explicit that the categorical is ordered, although I don't know whether that actually changes the complexity of the model.